# optimize image inside desired folder

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am using webpack for bundling. I am using reactjs and django. I want the static files used by Django and reactjs be separate. I could minified image but the minified images are saved to the folder where the output file is bundled. I want all the minified images to be saved inside frontend -> assets folder. How can i do it so?

The project structure looks like following

[image]

**app** - its a directory where static files are kept for Django. Webpack bundles the react files to app.js and is placed over here because Django template need it to render in its template as `<script src='app/bundle/js/app.js'></script>`.

**frontend** - It's a directory where all the react files reside. I want the images to be inside this directory(assets/images/). Images that will be used in reactjs.

How can i do it so?

my webpack right now is configured this way

```
const path = require("path");
if(!process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
}

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join("../app/static/build/", "js"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "../app/static/build/"
  },
  devtoo: 'source-map',
  debug: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },
    {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]"},
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom output and public paths by using the `outputPath` and `publicPath` query name parameters:

```
loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&publicPath=assets/foo/&outputPath=app/images/"
```

But this feature isn't [published to NPM](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader/pull/81#issuecomment-262735438) yet. So unfortunatly you'll need to wait while it be published or clone and use this loader from github [repo](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader)